# ActiveRecord test Greater/Lesser Than inside Hash Condition

Tags: activerecord, hash, compare, conditional-statements, where-clause

**The Question: Is it possible to test within a hashed condition if an attribute of a joined table is greater/lesser than a value**

An example: test if actors age is greater than ageVariable:

- Is it possible to write **instead** of the **ARRAY CONDITION**:

  ```
  ageVariable = 36<br> Movie.includes(:actors).where("actors.age > ?", ageVariable)
  ```
- The **HASH CONDITION** something like:

  ```
  ageVariable = 36
  Movie.includes(:actors).where(:actors => { :age => COMPARE_LOGIC })
  # Where COMPARE_LOGIC is something like: (:age > ageVariable)
  ```

Answer (score 8):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions

Only equality, range and subset checking are possible with Hash conditions.